# The Filename or directory is incorrect when space is there in Directory Name in Python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, operating-system

Below is a small module of a remote execution program that sends commands and further, the command is executed and response is sent.

```
command = "cd Camera Roll"
command = command.split(" ")

def run_command(self, command):                         # This function analyses the command and decides what to do.
    try:            
         if command[0] == "cd" and len(command) > 1:   # Command for checking and changing path.
            if len(command) > 2:
                i = 1
                os_command = ""
                for i in range(1, len(command)):
                    os_command = os_command + " " + command[i]

                os.chdir('"' + os_command[1:] + '"')
                working_dir = os.getcwd()
                return "The directory was changed to " + str(working_dir)

            else:
                os.chdir(command[1])
                working_dir = os.getcwd()
                return "The directory was changed to " + str(working_dir)

        else:
            result= subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
            return result.decode()

    except:
        return "Some error occurred" + str(sys.exc_info())


result = run_command(command)
```

When the above command is executed the error is below:

```
Some error occurred(<class 'OSError'>, OSError(22, 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect'), <traceback object at 0x000001B36796D940>)
```

Please assume all the libraries are imported as I only posted relevant code and Thank you in advance.

Comment: The shell will do its own command parsing, and it will split on spaces. So you're generating a `cd` command with two parameters. You'll probably need to insert some quotes in the proper places.

Comment: Thank you, but I have already inserted quotes assuming command to be like   os.chdir('Camera Roll')

Comment: Try replacing `os_command[1:]` with `' '.join(os_command[1:])`.

Comment: That won't serve the purpose 'os_command[1:]' command was used to remove spaces as prefix not the ones in middle, As the directory has in middle.

Comment: Adding a list to a string will insert brackets and commas that don't belong. You should print the command you're trying to execute before you execute it, the problem will probably become obvious.

Comment: if you look carefully than you shall notice that there are two different variables command and os_command. os_command is a string not the list. The command comes out as       "camera roll"